# Reading http responses from a stream

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

This is in Python 2.7

I have a socket which is receiving multiple HTTP responses consecutively. Is there a way to read the bodies of each of the HTTP responses using some built-in module in python. I can read all the responses from the socket and then convert it to a stream using StringIO, but will still need to separate each responses from there.

I thought of using the content-length header at first, but it doesn't work for chunked responses. So before writing the code to handle chunked responses as well, I wanted to know if its already possible to do using some builtin module in python.

Comment: import requests

Comment: I don't want to use requests for sending the http requests, won't work for what I am doing. I want to just read each response from the stream

Comment: does this work?
http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.in/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html

Comment: no, that's not what I asked. It maybe fine if I had written the server side code myself. But that's not the case here. I am receiving http responses through the socket, not some stuff with fixed length. And I need to split the responses and of course extract the body of each response as well.

Comment: how are you reading the streams from the socket?

Comment: not sure what u mean exactly, I am using select module to implement a timeout on the receive and then just using sock.recv(bufferlength), sock being the socket and the bufferlength being some fixed length.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/httplib.html?highlight=httplib#httplib.HTTPResponse

Comment: Thanks. that works for me